# ParseExact, string was not recognized

Tags: .net, powershell

I have the following code:

```
$timeinfo = '01 January 2015 15:05:00' 
$template = 'dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss'
[DateTime]::ParseExact($timeinfo,$template,$null)
```

when I run it I get the following exception:

```
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not    recognized as a valid DateTime."
At DataBase.ps1:34 char:23
+ [DateTime]::ParseExact <<<< ($timeinfo,$template,$null)
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

The string format appears to be correct to me, what's the problem? why?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a month name `January` as a part of the string you want to parse. If you do not pass a culture to be able to parse that name back into a month number then the culture of the currently executing thread is used. Should that not be English then parsing will fail. To ensure that this does not happen as the culture of the thread is not guaranteed (unless you set it explicitly before) you should pass a culture format provider.

```
$formatProvider = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCulture('en-US')
[DateTime]::ParseExact($timeinfo, $template, $formatProvider)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple *cast* the string into a datetime using:

```
[datetime]$timeinfo
```